# android addTextChangedListener(TextWatcher) not working for the second time

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-textwatcher

I have 6 edit texts on my screen (used to enter 6 digits) 
If I enter 1 digit on one EditText field the focus should go onto the next one and so on.
If I hit back space on some edit text field the focus should come to the previous edittext field

For this I used the below code

```
 EditText2.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

            if (EditText2.getText().toString().length() == 1) {
                EditText3.requestFocus();
            }
            else if (EditText2.getText().toString().length() == 0) {
                EditText1.requestFocus();
            }
        }

        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }
    });
```

Normally , the ontextchange listener works if I don't hit a backspace on any of the edit texts. If I hit backspace on EditText2 and land on EditText1(some value on it is present) and try to enter something on it. The cursor is not going to EditText2 as addTextChangedListener not working.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you've probably set your `EditText` fields up with a `maxLength` of 1. Something like this:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/edit_text_one"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:maxLength="1"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:digits="0123456789"
    />
```

When your `maxLength` is set to 1, the `TextWatcher` will not be triggered when trying to enter additional characters. One way to solve your problem is when moving backwards to use `editText.setSelection(0, editText.length());` See below for a working example:

```
final List<EditText> fields = new ArrayList<>();

fields.add((EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_text_one));
fields.add((EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_text_two));
fields.add((EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_text_three));
fields.add((EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_text_four));
fields.add((EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_text_five));
fields.add((EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_text_six));

for (EditText editText : fields) {
  editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int start, int count, int after) {}

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int start, int count, int after) {
      for (int i = 0; i < fields.size(); i++) {
        // Determine which one of the fields is focused
        if (fields.get(i).hasFocus()) {
          if (charSequence.length() == 1) {
            // If the focused field has a character in it, move to the next field
            if (fields.size() > i + 1) {
              EditText nextField = fields.get(i + 1);
              nextField.requestFocus();
            }
          } else if (charSequence.length() == 0) {
            // If the focused field was deleted, move to the previous field
            if (i - 1 >= 0) {
              EditText prevField = fields.get(i - 1);
              prevField.requestFocus();
              // Select the text so it will be replaced when pressing another button
              prevField.setSelection(0, prevField.getText().length());
            }
          }
          break;
        }
      }
    }

    @Override public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {}
  });
}
```

Comment: I think it replaces the text on the same prev text field where the focus is on, but if the prev field already has a digit on it, I want the value to be placed on next edit text field

Comment: Okay so when you delete the digit you really don't want to move to the previous field? I'm not sure I clearly understand your requirements. You could try using `setOnFocusChangeListener` on your `EditText` fields and check if the field contains a value when it receives focus. If it does you want to move to the next field.